# Separar imágenes en HTML con sublime text 3

Tags: html

me gustaría saber cómo puedo separar dos imágenes en la página html para que no salgan pegadas una de la otra. Gracias sublime text3

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! sin ver tu html va a ser dificil ayudarte...

Comment: Hola Jose, por favor edita tu pregunta para detallarla mejor. ¿Cómo quieres separar las imágenes? ¿verticalmente u horizontalmente? ¿cuál es el código que tienes? ¿qué has intetnado? Lee [ask] y complete el [tour] para aprender sobre el sitio y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar saltos de línea en tu código, puedes emplear la etiqueta `<br>`, conocida como etiqueta de línea o de salto de línea.

Ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Separar imágenes en HTML</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Primera imagen -->
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Kubernetes.png"
        alt="Descripción de la primera imagen">
    <br> Salto de línea para separar las imágenes
    <!-- Segunda imagen -->
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Docker_%28container_engine%29_logo.png"
        alt="Descripción de la segunda imagen">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿La persona que pregunta quiere separar las imágenes verticalmente u horizontalmente?

Answer (score 1):

Además de usar `<br>`, si quieres que estén en la misma fila podrías usar `display flex`, tal que así:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.img {
    margin: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="url/de/tu/css"><!-- enlazas tu css -->
    <title>Separar imágenes en HTML</title>
</head>

<body>

    
    <!-- les pongo una clase a las imagenes para modificarlas con CSS -->
    <!-- encierro las dos imagenes dentro de un div para manejar los estilos del contenedor y le pongo una clase para poder darle estilos-->

  <div class='container'>

    <img class='img' src="url/de/ejemplo">

    <!-- le pongo una clase para modificarla con CSS -->

    <img class='img'src="url/de/ejemplo">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Prueba a ver si funciona y si te sirve, saludos.